# Calculate Azure Costing using Azure Billing APIs

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I am able to get the ResourceUsage and RateCard API using Rest Client (Postman) as well as Power BI.

I want to further calculate Azure costing using the APIs output. I went through the URL [Show azure cost analysis data using Azure billing API/SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481608/show-azure-cost-analysis-data-using-azure-billing-api-sdk) but it did not help me as the question is still not answered appropriately and also the Azure SDK for Python URL is not opening.

I also came across a Git code for Azure Usage and Billing Insights https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureUsageAndBillingPortal but I do not want to add more resources to subscriptions just for calculating the cost.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Please update your question and include what you did not understand about calculating costing. You did not mention that in your question.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I am building an in-house dashboard for reporting purpose and I do not know a way to calculate exact costing through Azure Billing APIs output.

Comment: I can understand your situation. However it is somewhat difficult to explain the calculation part for the entire billing. Here's what I would recommend: Run the usage API and pick data for just one meter (say Virtual Machine) and include data from the rate card for that meter (you can match by meter id) and then ask question based on that. HTH.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, the meterID mentioned in Usage API is not matching to the meterID mentioned in RateCard API. Any idea around it

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Have you selected the proper offer id for the rate  card? Please update your question with all the details instead of putting them as comments. Thanks.