# how to get resource cost with azure python sdk?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python, cost-management

i am struggling to figure out how to get the cost of a resource in azure with python sdk

i have created a client "BillingManagementClient"
but i have no idea how to start using it and find cost information about resources ,
can anyone share his knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

To get the resource cost with Azure Python SDK, Billing is available as a SDK. [azure-mgmt-billing 6.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-billing/)  and [azure-mgmt-consumption 8.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-consumption/)

**[_billing_management_client.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/c8291ac6cb0dbd865da03a88dd2bcb9279e2c4a6/sdk/billing/azure-mgmt-billing/azure/mgmt/billing/_billing_management_client.py)**

```
 def _send_request(self, http_request, **kwargs):
        # type: (HttpRequest, Any) -> HttpResponse
        """Runs the network request through the client's chained policies.
        :param http_request: The network request you want to make. Required.
        :type http_request: ~azure.core.pipeline.transport.HttpRequest
        :keyword bool stream: Whether the response payload will be streamed. Defaults to True.
        :return: The response of your network call. Does not do error handling on your response.
        :rtype: ~azure.core.pipeline.transport.HttpResponse
        """
        path_format_arguments = {
            'subscriptionId': self._serialize.url("self._config.subscription_id", self._config.subscription_id, 'str'),
        }
        http_request.url = self._client.format_url(http_request.url, **path_format_arguments)
        stream = kwargs.pop("stream", True)
        pipeline_response = self._client._pipeline.run(http_request, stream=stream, **kwargs)
        return pipeline_response.http_response
```

You can refer to [Show azure cost analysis data using Azure billing API/SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481608/show-azure-cost-analysis-data-using-azure-billing-api-sdk?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Getting started - Managing Resource using Azure Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-samples-python-management/resources/)