# Get Azure Resource Utilization by using azure COSTMANAGEMENT-API

Tags: azure, resource-utilization

Is there any way to get Cost and Utilization(CPU, Memory, DTU) trend of azure resources by using azure cost management apis.

Comment: You can refer to [Show azure cost analysis data using Azure billing API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481608/show-azure-cost-analysis-data-using-azure-billing-api-sdk), [Working with the Azure billing and cost management API](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip213.html), [Usage Details - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usage-details/list) and [PowerShell Script to retrieve Azure Usage and Cost/Pricing](https://gist.github.com/krist00fer/9e8ff18ac4f22863d41aec0753ebdac4)

Answer (score 0):

If you check this [Azure Cost Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/) documentation, then you will find that -

> The Azure Cost Management APIs provide the ability to explore cost and usage data by creating customized filters and expressions allowing you to answer consumption-related questions for your Azure resources.

But note that these APIs are currently available for **Azure Enterprise customers**. So you can use it if you have the Enterprise Subscription.

To solve your problem you can use the [Azure Consumption APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/consumption-api-overview). These APIs support Enterprise Enrollments and also some **Web Direct Subscriptions**. The Azure Consumption APIs **give you programmatic access to cost and usage data for your Azure resources**.

- You should use **Balances API**, to get a monthly summary of information on balances, new purchases, Azure Marketplace service charges, adjustments, and overage charges.
- And use **Budgets API**, to to create either cost or usage budgets for resources, resource groups, or billing meters.
- Use the **Usage Details API** to get charge and usage data for all Azure 1st party resources you have.

Currently Balances API and Budgets API is only for **Enterprise Customers only**.